# Check whether kafka topic exists or not in python via kafka-python libraries and without using consumer and shell commands

Tags: python, apache-kafka

[This is not a duplicate question because even though similar questions available on stack overflow but no answer is working in my case. Hence, I am asking my doubt here.]

I want to fetch list of available Kafka topics and check whether a particular topic exist or not. I wanna do this without using consumer and any shell command. I am looking for the solutions via libraries itself. So, to fetch list of kafka topic I did following -

```
import kafka
client = kafka.KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
topicList = client.topic_partitions
```

But, here I am getting error as -

```
'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'topic_partitions'
```

It would be a great help if anyone can tell me how to fix the error or suggest me any other solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t do this without creating a KafkaConsumer client. You get topic partitions in kafka only after they are assigned to a particular consumer.

You would have to use the [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.assignment) client to retrieve the topics.

Other way to do this is with [confluent-kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.1/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.list_topics) consumer client or the [admin](https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.0/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.ClusterMetadata) client, though the latter retuns metadata about the cluster including the topic paritions. With admin client, you can do something like this:

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient
admin_client = AdminClient({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9002'})
admin_client.list_topics().topics
```

gives

```
{'topic1': TopicMetadata(topic1, $N partitions),}
```

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close the question or post an answer of your own if you used that instead